# Where to start with C++ GUI?

Tags: c++, user-interface

Just wondering what a good place to start would be?  The program I eventually hope to make is a calculator for a windows operating system (School project)

Comment: "_Just wondering what a good place to start would be?_" You could start by reading a book.

Comment: You could start by letting us know your platform and operating system.  GUIs are not part of the C++ standard language, and require OS or platform support.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have good command of C++, Qt can be a good cross-platform starting point. 
Depening on the platform, you may choose to try native OS UI framework; MFC is Microsoft-only and somewhat confusing.
My money is on Qt.

Comment: There is also wxWidgets for Windows (and is cross-platform like Qt).

Comment: There are many GUI and window management packages or frameworks available for Linux (such as X Windows).  The OP didn't specify the platform.  There are also GUI frameworks for embedded systems that are not Qt nor WxWidgets (such as emWin).

Comment: Most -including Qt- rely on x11, but Qt is easier to start IMHO as an OO programmer.